# What is the LU decomposition of the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it just identity matrix product with identity matrix?

If I write $I = I \times I$, can it be proper form for LU decomposition $I = L \times U$?

Comment: Correct, see: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lu+%7B%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D%7D, of course this extends to any $n \times n$ case.

Comment: WHat is the problem with $L=I$ and $U=I$?